# UWP - ProgressBar visible value change only at the end of the Sub

Tags: uwp, progress-bar

I have written this sample to show my problem.
I have a progressbar (in async Sub but the problem is also in a Sync one)
When I increase the value i don't see anything on Video.

Only at the end of the Sub i can see the progress bar that now is at the top of the value.
Why ?

```
Private Sub Btn_ProgressBar_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Btn_ProgressBar.Click

    Me.BarraProgresso.Minimum = 0
    Me.BarraProgresso.Maximum = 100
    Me.BarraProgresso.Value = 0

    For i As Integer = 1 To 1000
        If i / 100 = CInt(i / 100) Then
            Me.BarraProgresso.Value = CInt(i / 100)
        End If

        For KK As Integer = 0 To 9000000
            Dim _MyApple As String = "Red Apple"
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you increase the value?

Comment: Sorry ...
Barra(i)  =  Me.BarraProgresso.Value = CInt(i / 100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button click handler is called synchronously on the UI thread, and you do busy waiting. Nothing is rendered until your handler returns. This works better:

```
private async void BtnProgressBarClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BarraProgresso.Minimum = 0;
    this.BarraProgresso.Maximum = 1000;
    this.BarraProgresso.Value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        this.BarraProgresso.Value = i;
        await Task.Delay(10); // Gives rendering a chance to run
    }
}
```

This is C# rather than VB, but I imagine the translation is managable. :-)